# SQL : Conditionally select column based on aggregate value

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements

The answer to this question:

Display the total number of operators hired each year.

is this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(YEAR(HireDate)) AS 'Count',
    YEAR(HireDate) AS 'Year'
FROM Operators
GROUP BY YEAR(HireDate);
```

But how would I modify that for this question:

Display the number of operators hired in each year where more than one operator was hired.

I tried to do

```
WHERE Count >= 1
```

or

```
WHERE COUNT(YEAR(HireDate)) > 1
```

but nothing worked. I did research CASE statements but I couldn't find anything suiting what I need to do, any idea?

Using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `Having` clause**

```
SELECT
    COUNT(YEAR(HireDate)) AS 'Count',
    YEAR(HireDate) AS 'Year'
FROM Operators
GROUP BY YEAR(HireDate)
HAVING Count >= 1;
```

[Read More](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)